# Best host for virtualization Windows XP on notebook

Tags: windows-xp, virtual-machine, virtualization

I bought notebook http://www.fujitsu.com/fts/products/computing/pc/notebooks/lifebook-a514/ , but i cann't install `Windows XP` on it or run clonned one.

Think to use virtualization.

What host best to use?

`Centos 7` + `KVM`

`Windows 7` + `VirtualBox` | `Vmware`

`Windows 10` + `VirtualBox` | `Vmware`

something else

In 7 there is built-in virtualization of `XP`. Can I clone there my XP?

Would be all devices virtualized?
Only WiFi may not be virtualized, because of using internal LAN.

How to virtualize `HDD`?
Direct mapping or single big file?

Requirement for virtualization: the least consumtion of resouces: memory, `HDD`, `CPU`.

Thank you for attention.

Comment: The best host is which ever host fulfills your requirements.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! When asking a question, please do include as much details as you can. It will greatly help people who are trying to help you.  E.g, what's the OS installed on the Lifebook right now?

Answer (score -1):

Windows 7 Professional or higher comes with Windows XP Mode. Windows 10 does not. In Windows 7, XP mode is already liscened so you shouldn't need an XP key,

Comment: Can i clone in this XP mode OS from old notebook?

Comment: @M-A-X - It would be difficult to do that.  You are better off just using a virtualization to achieve your goals.  There are 3+ virtualization products you can use on Windows 7, for free, to achieve your goals.

Comment: What OS use less resources (memory, hdd): 7, 8.1, 10?

Comment: I would assume Windows 7 uses less resources, only because XP Mode comes built into the OS and there is nothing to install. Also, older operating systems are usually faster so that works to your advantage

Comment: @M-A-X - What has your research shown?  You should select the host OS, which you have a license to, make your decision based on that.

Comment: @Ramhound I dont ask about license. I can use free Centos!

Comment: @M-A-X - You asked about which host OS. (Windows 7,Windows 8.1, or Windows 10) makes the better host.  I just pointed out, the host that is best, is the one you have a license to.   Cent OS, although free, still has a license.

Comment: @Ramhound please dont care about license... For virtualization i need not only OS. License is not problem and priority. Understand?